# Select statement against a particular table taking forwever

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to troubleshoot this problem for a while and at this point, I  have no further clues. The problem occurs only in a specific table in an SQL Server database:

Symptoms:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Particular_Table /* works fine */
SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM Particular_Table /* still works fine */
SELECT * FROM Particular_Table /* statement takes forever to execute */
```

It's a simple plain `SELECT` query, no joins, and other tables in the same database do not manifest these symptoms.

My observation is that the query gets close to the end, but never completes. The table is not huge, it has about 800,000 records.

I do not have admin access to the server and I am unable to check error logs, but I can run any query.

Any suggestion on how to locate the root of the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Funny, so `SELECT TOP <more than number of rows in table>` still makes the query go faster?

Comment: I had already checked that, with other tables in the database     SELECT <more than number of rows in table> works as if you were selecting the whole table. With this particular table in question that use case too runs forever.

Comment: Sounds like an open transaction has a lock on one of the rows of the table. Assuming that you are mistaken that 1000000 is larger than the number of rows in the table.

Comment: I've seen this happening. Probably some index is corrupt. Just reindex all indexes on this table. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: may be some transaction on the table is not committed @user2217057 EXEC DBCC OPENTRAN() and kill the process number

Comment: Thank you for all your helpful suggestions, everything I tried did not make a difference (reindexing, unlocking. etc.) until the DB admin communicated that a scheduled DB backup and verification job was found stuck and then recovered. In other words, the queries on that table started running normally again without any fix at table or stored procedure level. I assume the stuck job might have affected the DB resources and indirectly affected the execution of "select all" queries.